# How to get two different types of object from(same) arraylist and then store them in two different tables in database

Tags: java, sql, swing

I have two different classes – `Lecturer` and `SecurityGuard` – stored in `ArrayList<EmployeeData>`. Now I want to store them in database but I am getting `NullPointerException`. Code for saving them to database.

```
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Iterator iter = empData.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Lecturer tempLec = new Lecturer(0,"",0,0);
            Object obj = iter.next();
            if (obj.getClass().equals(tempLec.getClass())) {
                LecturerManager.addLecturerToDB((Lecturer) obj);
            }
            else {
                SecurityGuardManager.addSecGaurdToDB((SecurityGuard) obj);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Code for Manager Function

```
public static Boolean addSecGaurdToDB(SecurityGuard sg) {
    Boolean isADDED = false;
    String query = String.format("INSERT INTO SecurityGuards (EmployeeID,Name,HourlyRate,AreaAssigned) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')",sg.getId(),sg.getName(),sg.getHourlyRate(),sg.getAreaAssigned());

    try {
        isADDED = statement.execute(query);
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isADDED;
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace with the nullpointer exception

Comment: Please post a [mre].